# Change S3 backend store for default experiment

Tags: mlflow

Is there a way to change the default experiment's artifact location in mlflow? I have deleted the original bucket and would like to change the location for that experiment, but I cannot figure out a way how. Usually I just delete the experiment and create a new one, however the default one cannot be deleted.